# Keras history order problem when saving to GDrive

Tags: callback, keras, google-colaboratory

My aim is to save Keras logs (accuracies, losses, etc) to Google Drive after every epoch

I am using the following code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

class HistoryCallback(callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        with open("drive/My Drive/"+csv_path, "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(str(epoch)+","+str(logs)+"\n")
```

classifier.fit_generator(..., callbacks=[HistoryCallback()])

On my drive, I ***sometimes*** get strange output, like this:

```
25  {'acc': 0.963835932997043   loss': 0.10425430848152908  val_acc': 0.7071953016230713    val_loss': 1.1386645126622854   lr': 2.3961632e-06}

2366427 loss': 1.1117452404459112   val_acc': 0.5577092514076597    val_loss': 1.0548135743792362   lr': 4.980681e-06}  
2   {'acc': 0.6330444829612712  loss': 0.9205646275682026   val_acc': 0.5994126287500939    val_loss': 0.9518886575614829   lr': 4.956604e-06}
3   {'acc': 0.6983824379057777  loss': 0.7753418573921365   val_acc': 0.6314243757777277    val_loss': 0.8930798317542336   lr': 4.923029e-06}
4   {'acc': 0.7437319468601393  loss': 0.6659318362681732   val_acc': 0.6464023491359492    val_loss': 0.866631023106596    lr': 4.8800885e-06}
5   {'acc': 0.7798526863016054  loss': 0.5813610065455109   val_acc': 0.6637298091742786    val_loss': 0.8554121221564764   lr': 4.8279526e-06}
6   {'acc': 0.8090410167584868  loss': 0.5098161270401851   val_acc': 0.6657856092579039    val_loss': 0.8496283279291509   lr': 4.7668264e-06}
7   {'acc': 0.8317157712132858  loss': 0.45465362796302755  val_acc': 0.6734214392352559    val_loss': 0.8745797048056179   lr': 4.6969512e-06}
8   {'acc': 0.8491478913819287  loss': 0.4042509938624124   val_acc': 0.688986784105959 val_loss': 0.8465897937878288   lr': 4.6186033e-06}
....
```

As you can see, the ordering is messed up, epoch 0 is missing, and 2366427 is a portion of the accuracy with missing epoch number and a few preceding numbers

Has anyone encountered this before and knows how to deal with it?

**EDIT:**
I have noticed that after some epochs, the file on the GDrive is also 0 bytes and then on the next epoch it is filled back in

Answer (score 1):

A guess: your training is proceeding in multiple threads/subprocesses, so your on_epoch_end is fighting itself - concurrently-executing copies of it are all opening the same file in 'a'ppend mode, and (partially) overwriting each other's outputs.
Does the problem go away if you write to a per-epoch file, or serialize output another way?

Comment: Interesting thought, however why would on_epoch_end be executed more than once? I do not think this is the issue